# Use Schema.org for Article without image property?

Tags: image, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have implemented Schema.org in my project, I have added `Article` section but we did not have `image` so it shows an error

> A value for the image field is required.

How can I fix this error and is there any solution for using `Article` without `image` section?

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have an image, you can’t (and you are not supposed to) fix it.

This is not an error with your use of Schema.org. It just means that you don’t get [Google’s Article search feature](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles), which needs an image:

> The representative image of the article. Only a marked-up image that directly belongs to the article should be specified.

Ideally Google would mark it as info/warning instead of error in their SDTT.

Comment: I understand, but I need to fix it asap and is there any no-image option included in schema.org?

Comment: @Karthic: Well, there is … by not providing an `image` property. Schema.org never requires any property, so there is no reason to have an explicit way to convey that you have no image -- if you don’t provide the property, you don’t have an image. -- Why do you need to fix it?